# Cannot call AngularJS controller function on page load

Tags: angularjs

I would like to call Angularjs function on jQuery page load event. But always get undefined or failed.

Cannot figure out what is wrong in it. So i have created test page on plunker for testing.

`My Plunker Test Page`

Comment: Concept makes no sense at all within angular. Need to get out of the jQuery way of thinking  and use a directive or trigger the function within the controller. See: [thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14994391/thinking-in-angularjs-if-i-have-a-jquery-background)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by getting controller scope

```
angular.element($("body > div")).scope().openMe();
```